# What is the procedure for deleting a project in drupal.org?

Tags: community-official-site

I created a project in drupal.org but decided that a better name would better suit the project, so I created another one. I need to delete the old project.

What is the official procedure to delete the old project node?

Comment: We decided on a better project name. That is the reason. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your project contains code usually it is not deleted. In that case, you can select as Project classification ***Unsupported*** and as a Development status ***Obsolete***.

You can always create a post in the [Drupal.org webmasters issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/webmasters) explaining your situation and requesting the project deletion.

But I can tell you that if you have people using your module, they will not delete the project.

Comment: Yes, this is the only way. But they have a lot of rules revolving around deleting projects, particularly if people have downloaded and installed them. The most you can do is reroute people to the new one on the project page and mark as obsolete or abandoned.

Answer (score 2):

The official procedure is asking for the project to be deleted in the [Drupal.org webmasters issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/webmasters) by [creating a new issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/add/project-issue/webmasters). The project is not deleted if there is committed code, or there are issues for that project.

If the project has committed code, and you just wanted to change short name to the project, since project short names cannot be changed once the project is created, just mark the project as unsupported, after you created the new project, and committed code.

Possibly, you should also create a stable release for the new project, so the maintainers of those sites using the old project who receive a warning about the project not being anymore supported would find a production release to use.
Together this, you should also add a link to the new project in the old project page.

#### Disclaimer

I am a Drupal.org webmaster, and what I described is the procedure we follow when handling requests for deleting projects, and what the Drupal.org Infrastructure Team suggests to the webmasters who handle those requests.